# Is it possible to exit a function from a subfunction it calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

my question is pretty simple. Here is the concept:

```
from random import randrange, uniform

def match (x, y):
        if x == y:
                print("True!")
        else:
                print("False")
                return
def main():
        while True:
                match(randrange(0, 10), randrange(0, 10))
        while True:
                match(randrange(0, 10), randrange(0, 10))
        while True:
                match(randrange(0, 10), randrange(0, 10))

main()
```

As you can see, there are two functions. `main()` which loops through random integers until they match, and `match()` which the actual integers are passed into in order to be calculated, and **if** a false result is encountered, both loops should break. There are two problems with this code:

1. The loop never breaks, because the return only applies to the function to whom the code is run on. My goal is to stop the main function the moment a false result is returned.
2. It is possible to add if statements on **each** line that check for a False returned result. However, that would be very inefficient and not ideal at all. There must be a better way.

I should note that this is code I modeled after a problem I'm having with my actual code, which is long and can't be copy-pasted here without context. The same principle still applies though: Much like the code here, I must stop the main function from calculating further when the subfunction it calls calculates a false result.

How can I do this? My idea was to somehow stop the main function from the subfunction `match()`, but is this possible? If not, what options do I have?

Comment: I think you mean that you want to find a way to break all the `while` loop without having to modify every single `while` loop?

Comment: Believe it or not, showing us your actual code and your actual problem may be more productive. This is how XY-Problems are born.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
from random import randrange, uniform

def match (x, y):
        if x == y:
                print("True!")
        else:
                print("False")
                raise Exception()
def main():
    try:
            while True:
                    match(randrange(0, 10), randrange(0, 10))
            while True:
                    match(randrange(0, 10), randrange(0, 10))
            while True:
                    match(randrange(0, 10), randrange(0, 10))
    except:
        print("exit")
main()
```

This may not be the answer you wanted, but I suppose it could be helpful.

By using try and except to create a scope that include all `while` loop, you can exit the function via raising exception.

If you want to end the function entirely (not doing `try/except` in function), you can simply do this:

```py
try:
    main()
except:
    #something else
```

This also allow you to do it without modifying the function itself.

Comment: That would work out the same result, so I'm happy. Thanks!

Comment: @Myronaz Happy to hear that it works :D